# Why does firefox keep getting hungup after the fourth run through

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to create a bot that clicks on a link on my site, opens a tab, closes, and then continues the cycle.

This keeps getting hungup after the 4-5 cycle however.

I also cannot figure out how to simply close both of the tabs, and get the url again as to not have to quit.

Sorry if this is very basic, I am new to this. :)

I am using selenium, firefox webdriver

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from keyboard import press

while True:

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(10)

browser.get('https://pridedogecoin.com/')

sleep(15)

login_link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="slider-6-slide-6-layer-13"]')
login_link.click()

sleep(5)

browser.quit()
sleep(15)
```

Answer (score 1):

okay, you need to switch to first tab like below, also you should use `close` not `quit`, since `close` is meant to `kill current window instance`, where as `quit` will `kill` all of the `browser instance :`

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "D:\geckodriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()

while True:
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.get("https://pridedogecoin.com/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(60)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    current_windows_handle = driver.current_window_handle
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "slider-6-slide-6-layer-13"))).click()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(current_windows_handle)
```